# rsyslog compile from source

Tags: centos, gnu, rsyslog

I seem to be having trouble with my install of rsyslog from source

I downloaded and compiled, installed libestr libfastjson liblogging. They are installed in /usr/lib.
I downloaded and compiled, installed rsyslog
and it appears to be installed filein /usr/lib64

When I attempt to start rsyslogd I get the following message:
Failed to start System Logging Service.
Mar 05 07:19:46 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit rsyslog.service entered failed state.

```
rsyslogd -d
rsyslogd: error while loading shared libraries: liblogging-stdlog.so.0: cannot o pen shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Version CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)
UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

---

I create symbolic Link but new error occured

```
ln -s /usr/lib/liblogging-stdlog.so.0 /usr/lib64/liblogging-stdlog.so.0
```

--

```
 rsyslogd -d
    rsyslogd: symbol lookup error: rsyslogd: undefined symbol: fjson_global_do_case_sensitive_comparison
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: To me, it seems a problem on how did you compiled and installer libraries (BTW, you should use `/usr/local` (or you will lost quickly what are you libraries that you need to update). An error on installing libraries (or a missing ldconfig?)

Comment: Thanks, I wanna used zeromq module thats why I recompiled .... Let me try again with   PKG_CONFIG_PATH